# Is possible to generate WSDL with security header filled?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I'm currently working with WSDLs files and in my project I use Spring WS with DefaultWsdl11Definition to generate WSDLs from XSD. The point is that the header comes empty and I would like to generate a header with security tags already created.

I want to generate a WSDL file with this kind of header:

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>?</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">?</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

The WSDL I have today generates an empty header. I would like to know if it is possible to create a WSDL which generates a header with security tags already filled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use Apache's `Wss4j` with Spring's `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` by defining the following in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    interceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken");
    interceptor.setSecurementUsername("?");
    interceptor.setSecurementPassword("?");
    return interceptor;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you have any example how the WSDL would look like?

Comment: Did you get resolved the issue, am also facing the same issue where how to set actions value .. I have user id and password.